# Bulk data import into array field using Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have the following table in PostgreSQL:

```
+------------+----------+                   
|   Column   |   Type   |
+------------+----------+
| name       | text     |
| keywords   | text[]   |
+------------+----------+
```

I'd like to insert a whole lot of rows in it, but I can't figure out how to insert data into an array field. Using `BeginTextImport` does not work since the TextWriter doesn't accept arrays:

```
using (var writer = connection.BeginTextImport(
  "COPY table (name, keywords) FROM STDIN DELIMITER ';'"
))
{     
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        writer.Write(item.Name + ";");
        // How to do this?
        writer.Write(item.Keywords.ToArray(), NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Text);
    }
}
```

Using `BeginBinaryImport` gives an error: "*Can't close writer, a row is still in progress, end it first NpgSql*".

```
using (var writer = connection.BeginBinaryImport(
  "COPY table (name, keywords) FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)"
))
{     
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        writer.StartRow();
        writer.Write(item.Name, NpgsqlDbType.Text);
        writer.Write(item.Keywords.ToArray(), NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Text);
    }
}// Exception thrown here
```

How can we bulk copy data into an array field?

Comment: Text import is inappropriate for this case - it means you're responsible for formatting everything in PostgreSQL's text format (delimiters and all).

Comment: I just tried your binary code example and it works just fine - what version of Npgsql are you using exactly? What type exactly is your items list? Can you submit the full source code which reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 2):

What about [this](http://bytefish.de/blog/postgresql_bulk_insert/)? It references [this library](https://github.com/bytefish/PostgreSQLCopyHelper), which you could use (haven't used it myself so I can't comment on it).

If you don't want to take an additional dependency, you could at least look at what it does under the hood.

Comment: Thank you! The extra dependency is an issue indeed but based on how this library is implemented I noticed that I can better use BinairyImport. It is still not working (see my update) but i'm sure is a step towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Can't close writer, a row is still in progress, end it first NpgSql", is likely because the number of writer.Write items you use is less than the number of columns expected.